# Query DSL - Misunderstanding of filters

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a query that looks like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "constant_score": 
      "filter": {
        "missing": {
          "field": "parent_id"
        }
      }
  }
},
"size": limit,
"from": offset
}
```

My type has a `parent_id` and a `wall_id` field. How can I modify this query so that I can get all types that do not have a `parent_id` and do not have a `wall_id`?  I can't seem to decipher it from the docs. Thanks for any help offered!

**UPDATE**

I have the following query that works, but I don't like the catchall `query` on the title. Is there a way to do this without having to add a "catchall?

```
{
  "query":{
  "filtered":{
     "query":{
        "field":{ "title":"*" }
     },
     "filter":{
        "and":{
           "filters":[
              {
                 "missing":{ "field":"parent_id" }
              },
              {
                 "missing":{ "field":"wall_id" }
              }
           ]
        }
     }
  }
 }, "size":10, "from":0
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're almost there, you just need to use the `and` filter under your `constant_score` query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "constant_score": {
      "filter": {
        "and":[
          { "missing":{ "field":"parent_id" }},
          { "missing":{ "field":"wall_id" }}
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow, that's great stuff. I did have to add curly braces around the "filter" property, but it works. Thanks! BTW, this format is so finicky, is there a source of good documentation aside of the elasticsearch.org docs?

Comment: Whoops, thanks. There isn't another resource that I know of, but you may want to check out the slides for a presentation I gave: http://www.elasticsearch.org/tutorials/2011/08/28/query-dsl-explained.html

Also, I don't know what client you're using to talk to ES, but if you're familiar with Perl, have a look at the SearchBuilder, which is a more compact more Perl'ish syntax which gets translated into the standard ES query dsl: https://metacpan.org/module/ElasticSearch::SearchBuilder

Comment: I'm using node.js and the elasticsearchclient module. That's a great help. Thanks!